# Is there a hidden meaning?

Tags: words

If someone tells you

(your name), お前は...

what are they trying to say?

Comment: I think nobody can know what they are trying to say only by the phrase.

Comment: The hero (male) saves the evildoer (female). The girl is surprised because he shouldn't have done that as she had destroyed his life. Then the girl says that phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just

> (Name), you ...
>   　*or*
>   (Name), you are such a ...

with the remaining part left unsaid. There is no common or known hidden meaning in such an expression, and you have to guess her feeling purely from the context. The sentence can imply "You're genius", "You're such a kind person", "You're an idiot" or whatever.

Comment: Nice thanks!!!!!!!! Could it also be "You are in love with me"?

Comment: It surely can mean that in a certain context. I don't know if it's the natural interpretation in the story you're reading.

Comment: when you say "surely" it means it is usually that way? Those words are usually used to say someone's in love?

Comment: @Cool Naruto means 'certainly' by 'surely'. It's not usual.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say "it certainly can".

Comment: So to say "you are in love with me" you normally use other words.  What words would be usually used to say "you are in love with me"?

Comment: Naruto, can you please answer 1 question? since お前は means you or you are... what particles are usually used to say "you are" (in love). I think it would be あなたは but I'd like to confirm it.

Comment: It depends on the **context**, not the wording.  「お前は...」 may well mean "Y-you're... (interested in me)?" or something like that, depending on the context. Replacing お前は with あなたは does nothing for the general meaning of the sentence.